# How to handle value type conversion in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm new in Spring and I am faced with a value type conversion issue.
When typing String to Free Pass field which is required Integer, I'm expecting to get custom error message "Invalid number" from the properties file, but I'm getting:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Integer for property freePasses; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sdf"
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing some java libs?

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        StringTrimmerEditor stringTrimmerEditor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmerEditor);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel) {
        theModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "customer-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer,
            BindingResult theBindingResult
    ) {
        if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "customer-form";
        } else {
            return "customer-confirmation";
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

public class Customer {

    @NotNull(message="is required")
    @Min(value = 0, message = "cannot be less than 0")
    @Max(value = 10, message = "cannot be more than 10")
    private Integer freePasses;
    
    public Integer getFreePasses() {
        return freePasses;
    }

    public void setFreePasses(Integer freePasses) {
        this.freePasses = freePasses;
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.autosdet.autosdetmvc" />

    <util:properties  id="countryOptions" location="classpath:countries.properties" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames" value="messages" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Form:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Custome Form</title>
    <style>
        .error {color: red}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Fill out the form.Asterisk (*) required.
    <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">
        Free Passes (*): <form:input path="freePasses" />
        <form:errors path="freePasses" cssClass="error" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form:form>
    <br><br>
    <a href="/autosdet_mvc_war_exploded">Main Menu</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Properties:

```
type.Mismatch.customer.freePasses=Invalid number
```

Comment: you could try 3 approach: 1. commenting out the initbinder 2. using try catch 3. set debug pointers in the locations I mentioned and run the spring application in debug mode.

Comment: You won't get to the validation. It already fails way before that in the conversion of a String to a number (which is what the error is telling you). That being said the message key should be `typeMismatch.customer.freePasses` and not `type.Mismatch.customer.freePasses`.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sdf"

String-to-Integer conversion in Spring is executed with `Integer.parseInt()` or `Integer.valueOf()`. Apparently your input `"sdf"` cannot be converted into a numeric value unlike e.g. `"12345"`.

I'd check the value you actually pass into your form, namely `freePasses` parameter. It looks like you are feeding their some text, not numbers:

```
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">
        Free Passes (*): <form:input path="freePasses" />
        <form:errors path="freePasses" cssClass="error" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form:form>
```